# A question about a route of a point that travels in a particular way through the plane

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know exactly how to classify this question. It is not from any homeworks, just something I've been wondering about.

Let's say that in the beginning of an experiment ( the beginning is $t=0$ secs) we have two points on the plane: one on $(0,0)$ and one on $(0, 1)$.

They start moving by the following rules:

1. The point that was on $(0,0)$ moves right, on the $x$-axis, in a constant speed of $1~\text{m}/\text{s}$.
2. The point that was on $(0,1)$ also moves in a constant speed of $1~\text{m}/\text{s}$, but its direction changes, so that the direction of its speed is always directed to the first point (like a missile that follows a moving object).

I hope I made myself clear. 
My question is: Is there a nice formula for the location of the second point on the plane for a given time $t$? How can it be derived? And what if we change the ratio between the constant speeds?

Thank you for your time reading my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the first point's position be $(t,0)$, and the second $(x(t),y(t))$.

We have that the direction of the second point is proportional to the difference between the points:

$$(x'(t), y'(t))\propto(t - x(t), -y(t))$$

But, since the speed is constant, we must have that:

$$(x'(t), y'(t))=\left(\frac{t-x(t)}{\sqrt{(t - x(t))^2 + y^2(t)}}, -\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt{(t - x(t))^2 + y^2(t)}}\right)$$

With $x(0) = 0, y(0) = 1$.

Now we must solve the differential equation.

**Addendum**

This equation does have a closed solution involving the Lambert $W$-function, which can be obtained by moving to polar coordinates, but it gets very ugly - If anyone can offer a simpler solution, I'd be glad to hear of one. The solution is also closely related to a similar problem, that of the [Tractrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html), which has constant distance rather than constant speed.

In any case, here is what the resulting curve looks like, for $t\in[0,1]$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea about handling such equations?
And does anyone know about a site in which I can simulate these things?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to explicitly solve this, though transferring coordinates to polar seems to be a good direction to take.

Comment: The tractrix problem is very interesting, thanks!